# Nokogiri Timeout::Error when scraping own site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

Nokogiri works fine for me in the console, but if I put it anywhere... Model, View, or Controller, it times out.

I'd like to use it 1 of 2 ways...

**Controller**

```
def show
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(design_url(@design)))
  images = doc.css('.well img') ? doc.css('.well img').map{ |i| i['src'] } : []
end
```

or...

**Model**

```
def first_image
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://localhost:3000/blog/#{self.id}"))
  image = doc.css('.well img')[0] ? doc.css('.well img')[0]['src'] : nil
  self.update_attribute(:photo_url, image)
end
```

Both result in a timeout, though they work perfectly in the console.

Comment: can you provide some more info on the error you get? You could copy your error trace here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, with tyler's advice I dug into what I was doing a bit more.  Because of the disconnect that ckeditor has with the images, due to carrierwave and S3, I can't get any info direct from the uploader (at least it seems that way to me).

Instead, I'm sticking with nokogiri, and it's working wonderfully.  I realized what I was actually doing with the `open()` command, and it was completely unnecessary.  Nokogiri parses HTML.  I can give it HTML in for form of `@design.content`!  Duh, on my part.

So, this is how I'm scraping my own site, to get the images associated with a blog entry:

**designs_controller.rb**

```
def create
  params[:design][:photo_url] = Nokogiri::HTML(params[:design][:content]).css('img').map{ |i| i['src']}[0]
  @design = Design.new(params[:design])
  if @design.save
    flash[:success] = "Design created"
    redirect_to designs_url
  else
    render 'designs/new'
  end
end

def show
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  @categories = @design.categories
  @tags = @categories.map {|c| c.name}
  @related = Design.joins(:categories).where('categories.name' => @tags).reject {|d| d.id == @design.id}.uniq
  set_meta_tags og: {
    title: @design.name,
    type: 'article',
    url: design_url(@design),
    image: Nokogiri::HTML(@design.content).css('img').map{ |i| i['src']},
    article: {
      published_time: @design.published_at.to_datetime,
      modified_time: @design.updated_at.to_datetime,
      author: 'Alphabetic Design',
      section: 'Designs',
      tag: @tags
    }
  }
end
```

The Update action has the same code for Nokogiri as the Create action.

Seems kind of obvious now that I'm looking at it, lol.  I dwelled on this for longer than I'd like to admit...

Answer (score 2):

When you run your Nokogiri code from the console, you're referencing your development server at `localhost:3000`. Thus, there are two instances running: one making the call (your console) and one answering the call (your server)

When you run it from within your app, you are referencing the app itself, which is causing an infinite loop since there is no available resource to respond to your call (that resource is the one making the call!).  So you would need to be running multiple instances with something like Unicorn (or simply another localhost instance at a different port), and you would need at least one of those instances to be free to answer the Nokogiri request.

If you plan to run this in production, just know that this setup will require an available resource to answer the Nokogiri request, so you're essentially tying up 2 instances with each call.  So if you have 4 instances and all 4 happen to make the call at the same time, your whole application is screwed.  You'll probably experience pretty severe degradation with only 1 or 2 calls at a time as well...

Comment: Is this why nokogiri scraping is usually done as a rake task?

Comment: No, not really. Usually you're scraping a different site, so it just looks like another web request to them and may take a few seconds on your end.  I can't really think of a good use case for scraping your own site since whatever data you need to get can probably be gotten through a database call and/or any methods you define, both of which will be orders of magnitude faster than using Nokogiri to scrape your own HTML.

Comment: I have to agree.  Its purpose is in photo scraping blog entries.  It scrapes (or would) each entry and grabs the src (which is on aws s3) to save to my actual database for quicker grabbing.  The other purpose I had in mind was for scraping all of the images from an entry to pass as an array to facebook's open graph meta tags.  How would you handle these circumstances?

Comment: How are the images getting onto the page in the first place?  Presumably you are have some kind of code in your view to place the image url into your HTML in the first place, right?

Comment: Ckeditor, through carrierwave, through fog, to my amazon S3 bucket. I mean... I know the paths to the images, I was just hoping to 'scrape' the info to make it easier on myself.

Comment: I think you're probably making things quite a bit harder on yourself.  If you just need the url, carrierwave should provide you with those methods when you mount the uploader.  E.g. `Post.image_url(:thumb)` could return something like `"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/9/thumb_image.jpg"`, depending on how you have it setup. If you need the url with some HTML around it, you can use a helper method or a partial to do that.

Comment: I agree with you, again... definitely making this hard on myself.  I looked over my app... I checked the uploaders.  I checked ckeditor's controllers and models.  The model doesn't save information about the actual picture (there's no path to the image).  So, I'm not sure when to grab this info.  If I upload 3 pictures to an article, I'd want to send each of the addresses to an array, as they're brought in, right?  Where, though?  Excuse my ignorance, I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what default value of timeout. 
But you can specify some timeout value like below.

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('localhost')
http.open_timeout = 100
http.read_timeout = 100
Nokogiri.parse(http.get("/blog/#{self.id}").body)
```

Finally you can find what is the problem as you can control timeout value.

Comment: I'm not picking up what you're setting down =/